# Unable to start multiple instances of node webkit app

Tags: node-webkit

I added "single-instance":false to my package.json file but still I am unable to start multiple instances of my node-webkit app.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1",
  "main": "index.html",
  "single-instance": false,
  "window": {
    "frame": true,
    "toolbar": false,
    "resizable": true,
    "min_width": 1000,
    "min_height": 800,
    "icon": "public/images/favicon.png"
  },
  "nodejs": true,
  "node-main": "server.js"
}
```

Comment: Please mention that you're trying in nwjs v0.13 and higher...

Comment: @Jry9972 hey I too face the same issue. I'm using the version nwjs-sdk-v0.22.3-win-ia32

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to do it: if you replace the name of the application inside package.json each time an instance is launched, the next one will open, as nwjs won't see the same name on the launched app.

Change the version name after the app name, for example: "myapp v1", "myapp v2", or append the timestamp. Just check if these changes won't break other functions of your app.

Answer (score -1):

"by default node-webkit only allows one instance of your app if your app is a standalone package"

You have to include in your package.json file the following:
"single-instance": false

You can find here the documentation:
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/manifest-format

Comment: He already has "single-instance": false in the package.json file.  It appears to be a defunct feature since v0.13 https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4797